# Angular unknown provider with factory wrapped in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, factory

I am getting an unknown provider error (injector) with a factory when I declare using an anonymous function:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').factory('errorCodeFactory', errorCodeFactory);

    function errorCodeFactory() {
        var factory = {
            getMessage: getMessage
        };

        return factory;

        function getMessage(errorObject) {
            return "hi";
        };
    };
});
```

If I declare without wrapping it in a function, it works:

```
angular.module('app').factory('errorCodeFactory', function() {
    var factory = {};

    factory.getMessage = function (errorObject) {
        return "hi";
    };
    return factory;
});
```

Not sure why the first example doesn't work but the second does. I also have other factories using the same method as first example and they work. I must be missing something.

Comment: Can you post a demo to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was a missing set of parenthesis on the end of the wrapping function

Works:

```
(function () {

})();
```

Doesn't work:

```
(function () {

});
```